# airodump-ng: No beacons from WiFi Access Piont

Tags: wifi, aircrack-ng, airodump-ng

I'm trying to monitor my Access Point "My AP" with a "TP-Link Archer T3U Plus AC1300".

I put it in monitor mode:

```
ip link set wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ip link set wlan0 up
```

_

```
$iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:""  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=-100 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

airodump-ng receives beacons from other Access Points from my neighbors but not from my "My AP":

```
$airodump-ng  --band abg wlan0



BSSID  PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH   MB   ENC CIPHER  AUTH ESSID

 XXXXX   -1        0       24    0   1   -1   WPA              <length:  0>                                       
 My AP  -46        0      218    0   6  405   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  YYY          <=== HERE
 XXXXX  -60     3713     1572    1   1  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  AAA                                     
 XXXXX  -63     5010     1910    9   1  195   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  AAA
 XXXXX  -66     5531        0    0   1  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  AAA
 XXXXX  -72     5362        0    0   1  130   WPA2 CCMP   PSK  AAA

 BSSID  STATION     PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes

 XX     AAA         -85   0 - 1e     0      204                                                            
 XX     AAA         -1    1e- 0      0       22                                                            
 XX     AAA         -74   1e- 1      0      254                                                            
 XX     AAA         -80   1e- 1e     0      813                                                            
 XX     AAA         -66   1e- 1e     0      636                                                            
 XX     AAA         -74   1e- 6     14      100                                                            
 XX     AAA         -86   1e- 1      0       10
```

Info:

- AP is FRITZ!Box 7490
- AP is a Mesh with a Fritz Repeater
- AP has no hidden SSI. I can see it in my phone and connect to it.
- AP is 2,4 GHz and 5 GHz

Why I don't receive any beacons from my Access Point but from other in my area?

Comment: Not sure how airmon-ng knows the SSID when it doesn't see a beacon containing the extended service set.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the Wi-Fi standard of my Access Point (2.4GHz)
from Wi-Fi 4 (802.11g+n)
to   Wi-Fi 4 (802.11b+g+n)

Now I receive beacons for 2.4GHz.